# Dedekind sum is a product of sawtooth function

Tags: multivariate-cryptography

"The Dedekind sum is a product of a sawtooth function." This sentence does not make sense to me. A [sawtooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave) is a kind of wave for sound generation. But in the realms of cryptography, the [Dedekind sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_sum) seems to use these sawtooth functions.

Could anyone please explain how the sawtooth function are used for the Dedekind sum?

Comment: I have to admit that I'm confused. Where did you encounter Dedekind sums in the context of cryptography? Did you have a look at [the wikipedia page for them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_sum) yet? The page actually defines the sawtooth function and you can use it as a product in the definition of the Dedekind sum.

Comment: @SEJPM Fixed the fix. Should we migrate to Math? I don't see any cryptography in here. shamim, please supply a *cryptographic reference* where you encountered the Dedekind sum.